Error with C code when compiling with assembly code
I'm currently using a book to learn a little bit of assembly. The part of the book I'm in is about malloc and free. To understand it better the book provides assembly code that creates a simple malloc and free implementation, which is then used by another small c program:
#include<stdio.h>

void *allocate(int);
void deallocate(void *);

int main() {

    char *a1 = allocate(500);
    char *a2 = allocate(1000);
    char *a3 = allocate(100);

    fprintf(stdout, "Allocations: %d, %d, %d\n", a1, a2, a3);

    deallocate(a1);

    char *a4 = allocate(1000);
    char *a5 = allocate(250);
    char *a6 = allocate(250);
    fprintf(stdout, "Allocations: %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6);

    fscanf(stdin, "%s", a5);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", a5);

}

I get the assembly code but after compiling the two together in the Linux terminal with:
gcc -static allocate.s usealloc.c -o usealloc


I receive multiple errors like this:
usealloc.c:12:40: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
   12 |         fprintf(stdout, "Allocations: %d, %d, %d\n", a1, a2, a3);
      |                                       ~^             ~~
      |                                        |             |
      |                                        int           char *
      |                                       %s


I'm assuming %d is expecting an argument of int, which is in conflict of a1, a2, and a3 being declared char. I'm not really familiar with C just yet but I figured a published book wouldn't have   a simple issue like this, so any help is appreciated!

Perhaps you shouldn't be using that book. "published book wouldn't have a simple issue like this" I have bad news for you...

I recommend you learn C first, before learning assembly. Or at least don't try to learn both at the same time. Pick one and learn that properly first, then the other, before trying to mix them.

Re “I figured a published book wouldn't have a simple issue like this”: This is incorrect figuring. Published books have errors.

@n.m.couldbeanAI The book has been fine up until this point. It's been easy to grasp. In any case, a good lesson I suppose.

@Someprogrammerdude Thank you for the advice. I agree, that would be silly to learn both at once. The book is marketed as a beginners guide. C will be my next language to learn.

The Definitive C Book Guide and List

If the book is old, it might have been written when it was common for ints and pointers to be the same size. At a time when compilers hadn't learned to check the format strings.

First off, it's great that you're paying attention to warnings! It's a shame the book authors didn't.
You can make this warning go away if you explicitly cast those character pointers to int:
fprintf(stdout, "Allocations: %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", (int) a1, (int) a2, (int) a3, (int) a4, (int) a5, (int) a6);

Better yet, use %p instead, which is used for printing nicely formatted pointers like 0x600000de0000:
fprintf(stdout, "Allocations: %p, %p, %p, %p, %p, %p\n", a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6);


%p is specified to take an argument of type void *, not char *. Some compilers will warning about this. So arguments to be printed with %p should be cast to void *.

Good to know. Clang didn't complain, but yeah, OP can (void *) if needed

Thank you both! This compiled with no errors after trying both solutions, but I will keep this in mind.
